# Calculate third derivative of multivariate function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I really need to understand the algorithm of solving these kind of problems.

$$f(x,y) = x^3 + y^3 +xy(x - y)$$
I need to calculate:
$$f'''_{xxy}(1,1) + f'''_{xxx}(1,1) + f'''_{yyy}(1,1)$$

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

$$ f_x = 3x^2 +2xy - y^2;
f_{xx} = 6x + 2y;
f_{xxx} = 6; f_{xxy} = 2;
f_y = 3y^2 + x^2 - 2xy;
f_{yy} = 6y - 2x;
f_{yyy} =6
$$
So the answer to your question is $14$.

Comment: Thank you very much, you really helped!